# Python/Panda - merge csv according to join table/csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-structures

I have a problem regarding the merge of 2 csv files. I have 2 files containing multiples columns of data including unique id's and another file that maps those Id's of file 1 to an id of file 2. So I have basically a .

Now I want to create a new csv file with data from file 1 and 2 joined according to the id mappings in my join csv.

Heres an example how my data looks:

CSV1-Customer

```
ID, Name, Lastname
1,  Peter, Pan
2,  Hank,  Tank
```

CSV2-Address

```
ID, Street, State
5,  Mainstr, US
7,  H Blvd,  DE
```

Join-CSV:

```
CID, AID
1,   5
2,   7
```

What I want:

```
ID, Name, Lastname, Street, State
    1,  Peter, Pan,  Mainstr, US
    2,  Hank,  Tank  H Blvd,  DE
```

I would really appreciate help or an example how I can solve this issue with python / panda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for DataFrames with double [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), last remove unnecessary columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
df3 = pd.read_csv(file3)

df = (df3.merge(df1, left_on='CID', right_on='ID')
         .merge(df2, left_on='AID', right_on='ID', suffixes=('','_'))
         .drop(['CID','AID','ID_'], axis=1))
print (df)
   ID   Name Lastname   Street State
0   1  Peter      Pan  Mainstr    US
1   2   Hank     Tank   H Blvd    DE
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I get a key error however on the first merge for 'ID'. Just for my understanding: the `left_on` is the key from the join table and `right_on` is the key from the source table, correct?

Comment: @JohnnyKonfetti - check columns names, `print (df1.columns.tolist())`

Comment: `df1` now works but in `df3` the join table the header list is just 1 string and not multiple strings.

Comment: @JohnnyKonfetti - what is separator in `csv3` ?

Comment: delimiter is `;` in all files. I solved the issue now with `pd.read_csv("df3.csv", sep='delimiter', delimiter=';', header=0)`. The solutio seems to work an I will now write all data into a new csv.

Comment: @JohnnyKonfetti - Simpliest is `pd.read_csv("df3.csv", sep=';')`